# Apache .htaccess settings for mapping requests on shared servers

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want the following structure:

```
|--- public_html
    |--- dist
    |    |--- index.html
    |    |--- style.css
    |    |--- script.js
    |    |--- blog
    |    |    |--- index.html
    |--- index.php
|--- .htaccess
```

And for apache to look first in `/dist/` to see if there's a match, then if not to use `/index.php`. How can I get apache to do this via the .htaccess?

But I don't want it just to redirect, but to serve the `/dist/` files as if they were in the web root, so:

```
example.com/blog
```

is served as such, but using the file from `example.com/dist/blog/index.html`.

I've had a good look through the documentation but I'm confused with the seemingly myriad ways of redirecting and mapping in apache. Which module would I use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if path available in /dist/ then use it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dist/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/dist/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /dist/$1 [L]

# otherwise forward to /index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```